# how to get python unit test overwrite variable from imported package

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

Trying to figure out how to overwrite a variable during unit testing:

```
#mainscript.py
import json

org_file = 'unitfile.json'

def load_json (file_name):
    with open ('{0}'.format(org_file)) as f:
       json_object =  json.load(f)
    return json_object

new_file = load_json(org_file)

def print_me():
    return (new_file['text'])

def main():
    print_me()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Unit test:

```
#test_mainscript.py
import json
import mainscript
import unittest
from  unittest.mock import patch

class Testmainscript(unittest.TestCase):
    # def setUp(self):
        # Not needed when using mock
    @patch('mainscript.org_file','unitfile2.json')
    def test_print_me(self):
        self.assertEqual(mainscript.org_file, 'unitfile2.json') # Correctly overwrites file
        self.assertEqual(mainscript.print_me(),'Bye World') #does not pass, still reading unitfile.json instead of unitfile2.json
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This test should fail because because I'm overwriting org_file with `unitestfile2.json` (which contains `{'text':'Bye World'}`) instead of unittestfile.json (which contains `{'text':'Hello World'}`)

But its currently passing because the variable isn't being overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "[mocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)", an example for your case:

```
import json
import mainscript
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class Testmainscript(unittest.TestCase):
    # def setUp(self):
        # Not needed when using mock
 
    @patch('mainscript.org_file', 'unitfile2.json')
    def test_print_me(self):
        self.assertEqual(mainscript.print_me(),'Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I'm still getting a passing result are you sure its mocking unitfile with unitfile2?

Comment: Not sure, It's how this is done but might need some changes, You can add a test to see if it does change:
`self.assertEqual(mainscript.org_file, 'unitfile2.json')`

Comment: I added the test `AssertionError: <Mock id='140009482389680'> != 'unitfile2.json'` . Im pretty sure its not mocking correctly

Comment: Try this: 
`@patch('mainscript.org_file', 'unitfile2.json')`

Comment: I just tried that and it does mock the file as a`self.assertEqual(mainscript.org_file, 'unitfile2.json')` test passes but.. its not overwriting the global org_file because `self.assertEqual(mainscript.print_me(),'Bye World')` does not pass

Comment: I see, you need to make `with open(...` a function and call it in  `print_me` to get the content, because your code now load the text before it get patched

Comment: This wasnt exactly what I needed to do but it did get my mind on the right track so thank you. Added the final answer below

Comment: Cool, don't duplicate answers tho, it's not the same but have pointers, an answer doesn't need to be 100% as your code, just a pointer helps a lot sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue is that I am overwriting the file as expected but when I call the test I am not using the mocked file. Wrapping the function seemed to work:

```
#mainscript.py
import json


org_file = 'unitfile.json'
def load_json (json_file):
    with open ('{0}'.format(org_file)) as f:
       json_object =  json.load(f)
    return json_object


def print_me(df_file):
    return (df_file['text'])

def main():
    print_me()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here I used the wrapped patch as an input

```
#test_mainscript.py
import json
import mainscript
import unittest
from  unittest.mock import patch

class Testmainscript(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('mainscript.org_file','unitfile2.json')
    def test_print_me(self):
        self.assertEqual(mainscript.org_file, 'unitfile2.json')
        self.assertEqual(mainscript.print_me(mainscript.load_json(mainscript.org_file)),'Bye World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test now work:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```